# Yii bad request

Tags: php, yii

Никак не пойму почему при вызове действия удаления, yii выдает ошибку (400 bad request)

вот правила ссылок:

```
'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
        ),
```

А ссылка на удаление выглядит так

```
http://site.ru/item/delete/3
```

При чем все остальные действия работают отлично

По-тестил кое-что и оказалось, что если создать экшн с другим названием (actionTest), то все отлично удаляется. Почему actionDelete не работает?

Comment: > Никак не пойму почему при вызове
> действия удаления yii выдает ошибку
> (400 bad request)  

@Виталий Леонов расставьте запятые. Долго не мог понять, зачем Yii удалять :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно Вы влезаете в какой то зарезервированный экшен Yii.

У меня так было, когда делал для коротких адресов экшен S(short) в контроллере и он совпал с экшеном actions. Потратил время, что бы разобраться, почему выдает 400-ю ошибку

```
public function actionS()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно он хочет так: http://site.ru/index.php/item/delete/3
Если хотите http://site.ru/item/delete/3, то надо добавить .htaccess
Могу скинуть свой рабочий.

Comment: там есть .htaccess. я же написал что остальные действия работают в таком виде